# Flex Ratio Not Working in Polymer ^1.7.0?

Tags: frontend, polymer-1.0, progressive-web-apps, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer

I am using Flex-ratio property, but this property is not working. I am sharing my code.
According to this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIARqr?p=preview), this property is working fine on Polymer 1.0.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-car/paper-card.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">

 <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex"></style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="horizontal layout">
    <div class="flex-2"><p>flex three</p></div>
    <div class="flex-1"><p>flex</p></div>
    <div class="flex-2"><p>flex two</p></div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based from this [blog](https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/), Polymer is dropping `/deep/` support in their elements and are encouraging people to use the `mixins` instead of the `classes`. *"Currently, the layout class stylesheet uses the [`/deep/` combinator](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) and therefore, works across all local DOM boundaries. Because `/deep/` is slated to be removed from the shadow DOM spec, this stylesheet will eventually be replaced by a set of rules that do not use /deep/."*

Comment: even with `/deep/` removed from the https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout-classes.html it is still broken

Answer (score 1):

I made this mistake myself.... need to import `iron-flex-factors` in `<style include="iron-flex iron-flex-factors iron-flex-alignment">`